# why values in <p:selectOneMenu> are duplicated after changing language in jsf?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, duplicates

I used for internationalization the JSF configuration, and I have a list of countries from the class `Locale` in `<p:selectOneMenu>`, but
I am facing a problem of duplicate values of the countries list in `<p:selectOneMenu>` when I change the language of the page

How can I correct this problem?

```
private List<String> countriesList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void setCountriesList(List<String> countriesList) {
        this.countriesList = countriesList;
    }

    public List<String> getCountriesList() {

        String[] locales = Locale.getISOCountries();

        for (String countryCode : locales) {

            Locale obj = new Locale("", countryCode);
            countriesList.add(obj.getDisplayCountry(Locale.ENGLISH));

        }
        Collections.sort(countriesList);
        return countriesList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't really tell without seeing more code, but from what I see my guess is the following:

Probably you call `getCountriesList` every time the language is changed and since it is adding entries to the list `countriesList`, which is not local to the method but a class member and therefore more permanent, those entries accumulate in that list.

Try doing

```
ArrayList<List> countriesList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

at the beginning of your method `getCountriesList` to make sure you are working on a local variable. That's the behavior I would expect from a method whose name follows the schema "getSomething".

Comment: thank you :) ! it's working fine now without duplication

Comment: That it works doesn't necessarily mean that it's the right way.